# Problems with global-variables affecting Unit Test results

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, global-variables

I have created a Unit Test with **Native Unit Test project** in Visual Studio 2017 for **embedded software** that is writen in **C code**. The software has many parameters that are **global-variables**, which  are reachable from the entire system.

That generates problems that a Unit Test, for example fuel monitoring, also affects the engine control unit test. If I run unit test separately, it works as intended.

So my question is whether there is an easy way to restart the application while the test is running between methods? So I can get a better control over which parameters have changed and do not need to worry about added new methods affecting the existing unit test cases.

Comment: It might be better to move the globals into a container and then pass the container around... then there's no need to restart anything; and you can just create a new container for each test.

Comment: One additional drawback of global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to have a setup stage at the start of every test that sets all the globals to predetermined values.

So you would call a function at the beginning of every test:

```
 SetGlobals( struct { a = ....}),
```

where you pass in a struct that holds all the variables you care about.

Then each test should have consistent behavior, and all variables would be reset to correct values between tests. (You'll still have an issue if you try to multi-thread the test runner, of course)

Comment: Be worried to take unnecessary time as there will be many test cases. That's probably the best way for me to solve my problem. Luckily it's simple threaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking for solution that does not require redesigning your code.

One way to manage this is to run unit test in debug mode by setting breakpoints to manually change the value of global variable when you reach to new method.

I used this method in different context earlier, however, I do not know if you can run in debug mode for embedded applications. In case you do, please remember to recompile the application post testing to remove -g parameter.